# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre del dispositivo bluetooth associado y conectado en Android?

Tags: java, android

Me estoy mirando la documentación oficial de [BluetoothAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html) el método `getRemoteDevice(byte[] address)` previamente le debes indicar la dirección mac del dispositivo asociado, si se captura el evento del bluetooth con `ACL_CONNECTED` en el parámetro `extra` se puede obtener.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Obtengo el dispositivo que se ha conectado obtenido de `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE`

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
           ... //Dispositivo encontrado
        }
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
           ... //Dispositivo conectado
               //Mostrar nombre device.getName();
               //Mostrar dirección física device.getAddress();
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
           ... //Búsqueda finalizada
        }
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
           ... //Dispositivo remoto pregunta por desconectarse
        }
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
           ... //Dispositivo remoto desconectado
        }           
    }
};
```

Lo que intento es obtener esa dirección `mac` sin interceptar la conexión, es decir que la conexión se ha realizado previamente y al abrir la app obtenga el nombre del dispositivo remoto que se ha conectado.

Answer (score 1):

Si necesitas conocer el nombre de un dispositivo con el que ya has establecido conexión pero ya no está accesible, puedes recuperarlo de la lista de dispositivos del BluetoothAdapter:

```
private String getDeviceName(BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter, String mac){

    String name = null;

    for (BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice : bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()) {
        if (bluetoothDevice.getAddress().equals(mac)) {
            name = bluetoothDevice.getName();
            break;
        }
    }

    return name;
}
```

Comment: Si algo parecido uso para obtener el nombre pero solo cuando detecto ACL_CONNECTED lo que no encuentro es como obtener mac del bluetooth del dispositivo conectado con el BluetoothAdapter

Comment: Para obtener la mac debes utilizar bluetoothDevice.getAddress() pero necesitas permisos especiales a partir de Android 6.0

Comment: @Pascual_Montesinos me refiero al dispositivo conectado el otro lado no el propio

Comment: @Webserveis bluetoothDevice.getAddress() devuelve la mac del dispositivo conectado del otro lado. En el ejemplo que he puesto, se recorren los BluetoothDevices que tiene registrados el BluetoothAdapter porque están vinculados o se han hecho conexiones contra ellos. Para obtener la mac local se utiliza getAddress() de la clase BluetoothAdapter

Answer (score 1):

Yo tomo así el listado de dispositivos vinculados y sus mac:

```
 BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevicesList = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();


for (BluetoothDevice pairedDevice : pairedDevicesList) {
    Log.d("BT", "pairedDevice.getName(): " + pairedDevice.getName());
    Log.d("BT", "pairedDevice.getAddress(): " + pairedDevice.getAddress());
    }
```

Comment: puedes explicar tu código por favor? :)

Comment: generas una lista con todos los dispositivos vinculados `pairedDevices` y luego con un `for` los recorres y vas imprimiendo en el Log el nombre y la dirección fisica MAC